# Como executar um programa em C no Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, json, c++, task, visual-studio-code

Eu estou tentando rodar um código (programa) em C no Visual Studio Code, mas não consigo achar as configurações necessárias.

- Instalei a extensão C/C++ (Microsoft)

Estrutura do projeto:

**.vscode**

- c_cpp_properties.json

- tasks.json

main.c

**Meu código:**

```
- c_cpp_properties.json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": ["/usr/include"],
            "browse" : {
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders" : true,
                "databaseFilename" : ""
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": ["/usr/include"],
            "browse" : {
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders" : true,
                "databaseFilename" : ""
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": ["c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/include"],
            "browse" : {
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders" : true,
                "databaseFilename" : ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
- tasks.json
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "g++",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "args": ["-g", "main.c"]
}
- c program
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

<sup>[Link do pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5jbf2W3s)</sup>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

O VSCode, apesar de se um editor e não uma IDE, permite compilar código através de alguns plugins. No caso de compilar códigos C/C++, no Windows, achei ele um pouco "chato". Levei uma semana para configurar.

Mesmo tendo sido a pergunta feita a mais de 1 ano atrás, acredito que algumas pessoas possam encontrar isso e eu possa ter ajudado de alguma forma.

O que fiz para compilar o código em C foi instalar o plugin [C/C++ da Microsoft](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)

Depois de instalado o plugin, baixe e instale o [MingGW](http://www.mingw.org/) com as funções de gcc para Windows.

No VSCode, crie ou edite o arquivo **c_cpp_properties.json**, para editar basta utilizar o atalho Ctrl+Shift+P e selecionar "C/Cpp: Edit Configurations".

Lembre-se de que a versão do arquivo citado abaixo pode mudar.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/mingw32",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/backward",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include",
                "C:/MinGW/include",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include-fixed"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "__GNUC__=6",
                "__cdecl=__attribute__((__cdecl__))"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include-fixed",
                    "C:/MinGW/include/*"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Para a linguagem C, não C++, basta remover algumas linhas, como abaixo:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include",
                "C:/MinGW/include",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include-fixed"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "__GNUC__=6",
                "__cdecl=__attribute__((__cdecl__))"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include-fixed",
                    "C:/MinGW/include/*"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Após realizar essa configuração, apenas adiciona `"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Default"` nas suas configurações de usuário.

Depois basta escrever o código e rodar com o plugin Code Runner.

Fonte: [GitHub da Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/MinGW.md)

Answer (score 6):

O Visual Studio Code é um editor de texto, não uma IDE, não possui compilador. Você pode compilar pelo terminal (se usar Linux ou Mac):

```
gcc -o executavel main.c
```

Comment: O que significa essa flag `-o`, sempre tive curiosiddade de saber mai nuca perguntei ;) ?

Comment: `-o` vem de `-- output`, ou seja, saída, o arquivo de saída daquela compilação, logo após essa flag deve se indicar o nome do executavel que a compilação irá gerar.

Comment: visual studio code compila até python amigos. e pelo que diz esse tutorial: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp, c e c++ também, porem só não estou conseguindo configurar meus json corretamente.

Comment: Na verdade não precisa ser exatamente o mingw, comigo o cygwin também funcionou, também funciona com o cmake (apesar de não falar se é possível na página do plugin), precisei criar duas tarefas, uma pra o build do cmake e outra pro make, a Microsoft poderia simplificar o processo de preparação de ambiente do VS Code, como um wizard de projetos por exemplo.

Answer (score 6):

Rapaz sofri demais para rodar C no Visual Studio (Windows), descobri na tentativa e erro e adicionei um script para facilitar o uso. Fiz assim:

- Aperta <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> no Visual Studio para Abrir as extensões e instale o **C/C++ da Microsoft** (para autocompletar os codigos) e o **Code Runner** (para Executar).
- Baixe o [compilador MinGW](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/downloads/68260/mingw-get-setup.exe/).
- Instale o MinGw (*anota o diretório onde instalou*) e abra o *MinGW Installer*, vai em **Basic Setup** e marca o `mingw32-base-bin`, **Installation** -> **Apply Changes**.
- Vai nas variáveis do ambiente no **Windows** -> **Variaveis do Sistema** -> **Path**, e adicione a pasta **bin** do MinGW que você instalou.
- Volta no VS Code -> Botão Direito no Code Runner -> Configure Extension Settings. Aba User -> Extensions. Procura **Code-runner: Executor Map** e vai em **Edit in settings.json** (O caminho aqui fica em *C:\Users\NomeUsuario\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json*) e deixa assim:

  ```
  {
  "git.ignoreMissingGitWarning": true,
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "editor.fontSize": 16,
  "editor.accessibilitySupport": "on",
  "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always",
  "editor.autoClosingQuotes": "always",
  "terminal.integrated.rendererType": "dom",
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
  "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
  "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": false,
  "code-runner.executorMap": {
  "javascript": "node",
  "php": "C:\\php\\php.exe",
  "python": "python",
  "perl": "perl",
  "ruby": "C:\\Ruby23-x64\\bin\\ruby.exe",
  "go": "go run",
  "html": "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\"",
  "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
  "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && start $fileNameWithoutExt.exe"
  },
  "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
  "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
  "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true
  }
  ```

Só precisa editar ou adicionar a linha do "c" e as 3 últimas linhas, o resto é padrão.

- Só escrever seu código, salvar na extensão .c e executá-lo com <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> que tudo será feito no CMD do Windows ;-].

> **PS1:** Se não funcionar, aperta <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> no teu código e seleciona C.
>
> **PS:** O anti-vírus aqui (*KIS*) fica bloqueando toda hora a execução mas é só permitir que abre normal.

Answer (score 2):

Não precisa de todas essas configurações. Basta instalar o modulo C da Microsoft. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>´</kbd> para abrir o terminal. Já abre na pasta do arquivo.

## Os comandos pra executar são:

```
$ g++ testeC.cpp -o testeC
$ ./testeC
```

<sup>Onde **testeC.cpp** é o nome do seu arquivo com extensão (em C seria: testeC.c)</sup>

> **PS.:**
>
> Minha opinião pessoal sobre programar em C,C++ o melhor a fazer é instalar o *code::blocks* (Windows, Linux ou Mac).

Comment: O melhor seria o visual studio por causa do MSVC e as ferramentas de depuração dele, achei estranho eles fazerem uma versão para o mac que é seu maior concorrente para computadores pessoais e não para o linux deixando apenas um conjunto de ferramentas para compilar programas linux no Windows, mas pessoalmente a code blocks, falcon ou devc++ não faz tanta diferença já que eles são só um editor, para mim o mais importante é o compilador que vai fazer a tarefa mais importante, a semelhança entre eles é que usam compiladores GNU.

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a resposta do amigo acima, você pode usar esse código para executar múltiplos arquivos, basta colar ele no arquivo C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json, mas antes é necessário instalar a extensão Code Runner:

```
{ 
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "c": "cls && gcc -g -o $fileNameWithoutExt *.c && $fileNameWithoutExt"
},
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, esse é um problema que eu enfreitei, quando comecei a usar o VS.
Se você assim como eu, gostaria apenas de ver a saída no terminal, e não perder muito tempo configurando, e fazer só uma vez de forma rápida e simples.
Eu utilizei o [**MinGW**](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/start) com a extensão do VS, [**C/C++ Configurations**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools).

Primeiro coloque o diretório bin do MinGW, como variável ambiente do Windows, junto ao PATH

Depois no VS, abra o C/C++ Configurations, (Ctrl+Shift+P ">C/C++:Edit Configurations (UI)")
coloque as seguintes configurações:

Caminho do compilador:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe
                    Caso não seja este o local onde está o MinGw
```

Compiler arguments:

```
-g
-Wall
-o
${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe
${filename}
```

Modo do Intellisense

```
gcc-x64
```

O resto mantenha, como está ou atualize para o mais recente, para compilador C ou C++

E então ele começará a gerar o seguinte arquivo **c_cpp_properties.json**

```js
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-g",
                "-Wall",
                "-o",
                "${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "${filename}"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Ctrl+Alt+N que começará a compilar e aparecer no terminal.
Caso contrário...

Answer (score 0):

depois de instalado o plugin c/c++ intellisense da microsoft
depois de instalado o plugin code runner de jun han

tem que colocar .exe depois dessas palavras no arquivo settings.json
tanto em "c": quanto "cpp":
a localização do arquivo é o seguinte endereço:

```
C:\Users\seu_nome_de_usuario\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json

$fileNameWithoutExt
$dir$fileNameWithoutExt
```

mudando pra

```
$fileNameWithoutExt.exe
$dir$fileNameWithoutExt.exe
```

essa é uma solução para windows pois executáveis compilados para linux não possuem extensão